# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - I don't need to loop over this

Tags: reactjs

I'm building pagination into my application, and I'm being told that I need a unique key on this component. I don't think I do as I'm not looping over anything for it.

This is my IssueOverview/index.js component render function

render(){

```
if (this.state.loading) {
  return <div>Loading ...</div>
}

if (this.state.error) {
  return <div>Error fetching data ...</div>
}

const currentPage = this.props.currentPage;
const limit = 8;

const pagination = {
  currentPage,
  limit,
  skip: (currentPage * limit) - limit,
  totalItems: this.state.issues.length
}

const issues = this.state.issues.slice(pagination.skip, pagination.skip + pagination.limit);

  return (
    <div className="issues">
      <div className="pagination-container">
        <Pagination 
          pagination={pagination} 
          changePage={this.props.changePage}
        />
      </div>
        
      {Object.keys(issues).map(key => 
        <Issue 
          key={key} 
          index={key} 
          issue={issues[key]}
        /> 
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

}

The issue is on the  component.

Heres the code for the pagination component

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const { totalItems, limit, currentPage} = this.props.pagination;
        const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / limit);
        const pageNumbers = [...Array(totalPages).keys()].map(x => x + 1);

        return pageNumbers.map(number => {
            return (
                <div className="pagination">
                    <a onClick={() => this.props.changePage(number)}>{number}</a>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this. It will resolve your issue

```
return pageNumbers.map((number, index) => {
    return ( 
      <div key = {index} className = "pagination" >
          <a onClick = {() => this.props.changePage(number)} > {number} < /a>
      </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: It would be better to use the page number instead of the index. Only use index as a last resort.